# RegEx: Obtener palabra especifica entre dos palabras

Tags: javascript, regex

¡Hola a todos! Me acabo de unir a esta comunidad ya que no he encontrado solución a mi siguiente problema, y me parece que este es el sitio indicado.

Tengo una expresión regular que únicamente permite obtener el contenido que está entre dos palabras, pero no necesito extraer todo ese contenido, sino una palabra en especifica (también las que se repitan).

Este es la expresión regular que tengo:

```
(?<=COMIENZO).+?(?=FIN)
```

Un ejemplo sería el siguiente string, del que necesito capturar todas las palabras Gato que estén ubicadas entre la palabra Animales y Cosas (excluyendo, obviamente, éstas últimas):

```
Tierra Gato Neptuno Animales Caballo Gato Perro Pato Cosas Sofá Cama Gato Caballo
```

Para finalizar, me gustaría agregar que estoy programando en JavaScript y, casi siempre, utilizo el sitio web regex101 para crear y modificar expresiones regulares.

Espero puedan ayudarme. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tendrías que proporcionar ejemplos para probar el resultado esperado.

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar. Acabo de actualizar el post con un ejemplo, espero sea entendible.

Comment: Está muy bien, solo que no logra capturar todas las palabras Gato que hay entre medio, solo una. De todos, modos, muchas gracias, trataré de ver cómo poder hacerlo con tu regex.

Answer (score 2):

La primera palabra "Gato" es sencillo... Lo difícil es si hay una segunda en el medio de los mismos delimitadores ("Animales" y "Cosas"). ¿Por qué? Porque al intentar la segunda coincidencia, el motor de regex ya pasó por el primer delimitador, y no tiene forma de volver atrás para verificar si realmente estaba "Animales".

La clave es usar el modificador `/y` (*sticky*), que obliga a que el regex esté anclado al inicio del texto o al final de la última coincidencia. Es decir que no va a intentar coincidencias desde el medio del texto.

Entonces, si estamos al inicio del texto, deberíamos buscar el delimitador y la palabra:

```
(^.*?\bAnimales\b.*?)\b(Gato)\b
```

¿Va a coincidir con todo el texto antes de "Gato"? Sí (es inevitable), pero usé paréntesis para separar en 2 grupos de captura.

Luego de coincidir con la primera ocurrencia y devolverla, el motor de regex se encuentra en una posición que no es el inicio del texto `(?!^)` y vamos a asegurarnos de que se cumpla esa condición para descartar que se trate de la primera coincidencia, y simplemente buscar una ocurrencia más:

```
(?!^).*?\b(Gato)\b
```

Uniendo ambas opciones, nos queda:

```
/((?:^.*?\bAnimales\b|(?!^)).*?)\b(Gato)\b/gy
```

Ahora bien, para ambas alternativas lo que nos faltaba verificar es que estén seguidas de "Cosas". Para eso, vamos a usar un lookahead `(?=.*\bCosas\b)` que se asegura de que coincida, pero hace que el regex no consuma caracteres, que vuelva a donde estaba, para poder seguir encontrando otras coincidencias.

```
/((?:^.*?\bAnimales\b|(?!^)).*?)\b(Gato)\b(?=.*\bCosas\b)/gy
```

Ejemplo:

```js
const regex = /((?:^.*?\bAnimales\b|(?!^)).*?)\b(Gato)\b(?=.*\bCosas\b)/gyd;

var texto = "Tierra Gato Neptuno Animales Caballo Gato Perro Gato Pato Cosas Sofá Cama Gato Caballo";

let match;
while ((match = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
    console.log(`Se encontró la palabra "${match[2]}" en la posición ${match.indices[2][0]}.`);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Acá dejo un par de funciones que hacen lo que se pide, son largas, pero me gustan más que los "choriRegex" jaja (a mi pobre intelecto le resultan más claras), por otro lado, si aparece un "Gatolico", no ocasiona problemas, y se pueden modificar y reutilizar fácilmente.

```js
var texto = "Tierra Gato Neptuno Animales Caballo Gato Perro Gato Pato Cosas Sofá Cama Gato Caballo";  

function suprimir( texto, inicio, final, dato ) {
    let marcaA = 0;
    let marcaB = texto.indexOf( final );
    let marcaC = texto.indexOf( dato, texto.indexOf( inicio ) + inicio.length);
    let salida = "";
    while( true ) {
        salida += texto.substring( marcaA, marcaC );
        marcaA = marcaC + dato.length +1;
        marcaC = texto.indexOf( dato, marcaA );
        if( marcaC > marcaB ) {
           salida += texto.substring( marcaA, texto.length );
           return salida;
        }
    }
}   
console.log( suprimir( texto, "Animales", "Cosas", "Gato" ) );
```

La primer función, usa tres variables que guardan posiciones del texto, la primera se inicializa con "0", la segunda con el principio de la palabra que nos marca el limite final de nuestro espacio de busqueda, y la tercera con la primer posición de la primer aparición de la palabra buscada, después de **marcaA**.
Dentro del while cargamos en **salida**, la sub cadena que está entre **marcaA** y **marcaC**.
Luego le asignamos a **marcaA** el valor de **marcaC** más el largo de la palabra buscada más uno (para incluir el espacio).
A **marcaC** le asignamos el inicio de la primer aparición desde la nueva **marcaA**, de la palabra buscada.
Dentro del if, se evalua si **marcaC es mayor que **marcaB**, en cuyo caso, se carga la última porción del texto, y se devuelve.

```js
var texto = "Tierra Gato Neptuno Animales Caballo Gato Perro Gato Pato Cosas Sofá Cama Gato Caballo";  

function suprimir( texto, inicio, final, dato ) {
    let arre = texto.split( " " );
    let bolA = false;
    let arr = arre;      
    for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if( arr[ i ] == inicio ) {
            bolA = true;
        }
        if( arr[ i ] == final ) {
            return arre.join( " " );
        }
        if( bolA == true && arr[ i ] == dato ) {
            arre.splice( i, 1 );
        }
    }
}
console.log( suprimir( texto, "Animales", "Cosas", "Gato" ));
```

Esta versión, generamos un array a partir del texto ingresado, una copia del mismo, y un booleano.
Dentro del for, el primer if, evalua si la actual posición contiene la palabra que nos marca el límite inicial, en cuyo caso cambia **bolA** a true, para que el tercer if, pueda evaluar **arr[ i ] == dato**, en caso de ser verdadero, quita esa entrada del arreglo original.
El segundo if, evalua si alcanzamos la palabra que marca el final de la zona de trabajo, cuando este se alcanza, nos retorna la concatenación del array original.

```js
var texto = "Tierra Gato Neptuno Animales Caballo Gato Perro Gato Pato Cosas Sofá Cama Gato Caballo";

function suprimir( texto, inicio, final, dato ) {
    let marcaA = texto.indexOf(inicio) + inicio.length;
    let marcaB = texto.indexOf(final);
    let subA = texto.substring( 0, marcaA );
    let subB = texto.substring( marcaA, marcaB );
    let subC = texto.substring( marcaB, texto.length );
    let reg =  new RegExp( " " + dato + " ", "g" );
    let subZ = subB.replace( reg, " " );
    return subA + subZ + subC;
}
console.log( suprimir( texto, "Animales", "Cosas", "Gato" ));
```

La más corta de las funciones, genera dos marcas, a la primera le asigna la posición del final de la palabra que nos marca el principio de nuestra zona de trabajo y a la segunda, el inicio de la que nos marca el final de la misma.
A partir de estas marcas, generamos tres sub-cadenas, que contienen respectivamente, lo que antecede a la zona de trabajo, lo que es nuestra zona de trabajo, y lo que sigue a la misma.
A la sub-cadena "B", le extraemos las palabras buscadas con el **replace**, usando el regex que construimos a partir de la variable **dato**, a la que le agregamos sendos espacios antes y después, para evitar borrar palabras que contengan esa expresión, por ejemplo "Gatos".
Finalizamos devolviendo la concatenación de las tres sub-cadenas.